# Docker container can't run jacoco agent with Java 12

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm trying to run java docker image with my spring boot app. I want to use it for API testing and I want to collect code coverage as well. However I'm not able to make jacocoagent run inside docker container. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing some setting somewhere? Regular bootJar runs smoothly when I don't add agent. Moreover I'm able to execute the same command without problem outside of docker env. So it doesn't seem to be a java bug.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  bootJarTestApi:
    image: openjdk:12.0.1-jdk-oracle
    environment:
      - "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/jacoco-agent/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/jacoco-report/apiDockerTest.exec,output=file"
    ports:
      - 2020:2020
      - 2021:2021
    volumes:
      - "./build/libs/bootJar.jar:/bootJar.jar"
      - "./build/libs/jacoco-agent/jacocoagent.jar:/jacoco-agent/jacocoagent.jar"
      - "./build/jacoco/:/jacoco-report/"
    entrypoint: ["java", "-jar",
#                 "-javaagent:/jacoco-agent/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/jacoco-report/apiDockerTest.exec,output=file",
                 "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev",
                 "/bootJar.jar"]
```

When I try to run it, docker says:

```
bootJarTestApi_1  | Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/jacoco-agent/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/jacoco-report/apiDockerTest.exec,output=file
bootJarTestApi_1  | FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
bootJarTestApi_1  | mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file
bootJarTestApi_1  | Unexpected error (103) returned by AddToSystemClassLoaderSearch
bootJarTestApi_1  | Unable to add /jacoco-agent/jacocoagent.jar to system class path - the system class loader does not define the appendToClassPathForInstrumentation method or the method failed
bootJarTestApi_1  | #
bootJarTestApi_1  | # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
bootJarTestApi_1  | #
bootJarTestApi_1  | #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f85d2728b07, pid=1, tid=7
bootJarTestApi_1  | #
bootJarTestApi_1  | # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (12.0.1+12) (build 12.0.1+12)
bootJarTestApi_1  | # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
bootJarTestApi_1  | # Problematic frame:
bootJarTestApi_1  | # C  [libc.so.6+0x37b07]  abort+0x297
bootJarTestApi_1  | #
bootJarTestApi_1  | # Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to //core.1)
bootJarTestApi_1  | #
bootJarTestApi_1  | # An error report file with more information is saved as:
bootJarTestApi_1  | # //hs_err_pid1.log
bootJarTestApi_1  | #
bootJarTestApi_1  | # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
bootJarTestApi_1  | #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
bootJarTestApi_1  | #
bootJarTestApi_1  | 
bootJarTestApi_1  | [error occurred during error reporting (), id 0xb, SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f85d2728b07]
```

Comment: Looks like the key line in error message is "mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file", search of this line in Google shows that it is always related to filesystem access, but can be caused by many things - from wrong OS configuration up to strange behaviors of some filesystems and bugs in JVM. And so I think that this is unrelated to particular agent, i.e. unrelated to JaCoCo agent, and you should be able to reproduce the same with any other agent. Try to use `volume` not for an agent file, but for directory; try to not use `volume` at all for agent and put it directly into image.

Comment: Thanks @Godin, it was exactly the issue.

Comment: I didn't understand to which "it" out of two suggestions to "try" you are referring, however anyway let's convert this comment into answer to mark as accepted ;)

Comment: I meant, that the library was needed inside of the container, not as volume :) Then agent was working as expected.

Comment: @JiangHongTiao what did you actually do to correct this please? Which library did you include and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the key line in error message is

> `mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file`

search of this line in Google shows that it is always related to filesystem access, but can be caused by many things - from wrong OS configuration up to strange behaviors of some filesystems and bugs in JVM. And so I think that this is unrelated to particular agent, i.e. unrelated to JaCoCo agent, and you should be able to reproduce the same with any other agent.

You can try

- to use volume not for an agent file, but for directory;
- to not use volume at all for agent and put it directly into image.